# Weird behavior in Blackberry when toggling virtual keyboard between two textboxes

Tags: html, blackberry, css

My web application is to be supported by iPhone, Android and Blackberry torch. The code is working fine except some issues. One of the major issues that i am facing is:
When on a page, there are some  tags. Some of which contains a text box for letting user's entry. Everything is working fine on iPhone and Android. But in Blackberry, when i am toggling between textboxes by using taps i.e. first open virtual keyboard by tapping on one textbox, then tap on other textbox, then tap again on the other one. In such cases, my background screen that should be displayed at the background of virtual keyboard, becomes completely blank(like it is not repainted as soon as virtual keyboard is opening and closing). If i slightly scroll, i get the background back.
Does anyone know about this problem? Is there any way i can retain my background or kind of refresh it?