# Blackberry Issue showing VirtualKeyboard and getting a blank screen

Tags: blackberry, virtual-keyboard

I have an issue when i show the VirtualKeyboard then appears on my screen a blank space over the MainScreen.
Some ideas to avoid this blank space?

Probably is the same weird attitude of the Blackberry OS with this guy...
[Weird behavior in Blackberry when toggling virtual keyboard between two textboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332022/weird-behavior-in-blackberry-when-toggling-virtual-keyboard-between-two-textboxes)

[image]

Comment: Do you have a screenshot you can provide to show what you mean?

Comment: Marc, I have posted the image , thank you...

Comment: Hm, how are you then showing the virtual keyboard?

Comment: @Elenasys i want contact you give me your email adress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private VerticalFieldManager manBackground;
private NewsList newsList;
```

problem solved, using the **onExposed()** method ...

```
protected void onExposed() {
   if (comesfromArticle){ //comes from an article (probably the Virtual Keyboard was showed)...
    manBackground.delete(manBackground.getField(0)); / Delete the manager that contains the list of news (newsList).
    manBackground.add(newsList);//Add again the newslist, so the blank space disappear...
    comesfromArticle =false;
    }
    super.onExposed();
}
```